# display last row in JTable,Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, jframe

I have a JTable. Maximum row displayed only four, while the number of all rows of eight. I want when the program starts the table will directly lead to the last row.

**here's when the program is start :**

[image]

**I want to like this when program is start :**

[image]

*table directly leads to the last row*

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the cell bounds for the last row, [`JTable#getCellRect(int, int, boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getCellRect%28int,%20int,%20boolean%29) will return the rectangle bounds of a given cell, so something like;

```
Rectangle cellBounds = table.getCellRect(table.getRowCount() - 1, 0, true);
```

Should give you the location of the given cell.

Armed with this information, you simply need to call [`JComponent#scrollRectToVisible(Rectangle)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) to request that the given rectangle is made visible.

```
table.scrollRectToVisible(cellBounds);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with the following code

```
  int lastRow=table.getRowCount-1;

  table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
  table.changeSelection(lastRow, 0, false, false);
  table.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(tblDetailInfo.getCellRect(lastRow, 0, true)));
```